# why gitignore my file is not adding up in iOS project?

Tags: ios, xcode, gitignore

In my iOS swift project I have MyView.swift which I don't want to commit so I want to add it in `.gitignore` file.. so I have added `MyView.swift` in `gitignore` but in source tree it appearing every time when I make changes... I also try putting `MyProject/MyView.swift` in `.gitignore` but no luck

Comment: If you have already committed it once before adding it to .gitignore you need to remove it from git

Comment: @JoakimDanielson not understood. please explain

Comment: Is the file already part of the repository? If so it will keep on appearing until you explicitly tell git to delete it.